# Max of a gamma function Python

Tags: python

how can I find the value of x at which the following gamma function is at its maximum  [see function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qTHh.png)

I wonder if there is a simple method with one of the libraries that could do this easily for me.

Ps. I'm considering the tranformation z=x/(x+c)

Thanks

Comment: this is a math question not a python question. provide some code.

Comment: in which interval? Perhaps better asked at math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: gamma function has not bounded from above...

Comment: the interval 0-infinity

Comment: This question should be moved to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: There is no maximum between zero and infinity. There is a local maximum between -1 and 0, another between -3 and -2, another between -5 and -4, etc.

Comment: You can simplify it by applying Leibniz Rule and Integration by parts. You will easily get the value of derivative of the function. If you are unable to solve, give me the link to your question.(On math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659094/max-of-a-gamma-function-python

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a library that can find (an approximation of) a local minimum in a given interval ? [`scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar) can do that. (For the maximum, just negate your function).

*Edit: `minimize_scalar` is better than `minimize` in your case, since you only have one variable.*

For the function to pass in, instead of integrating yourself, I believe you can use [`scipy.stats.gamma.cdf`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html)).